# MathJax 3: Is there any difference between \text{} and \textrm{}?

Tags: mathjax

After reading through the article [Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70632/101831) I'd like to know if there is any difference between `\text{}` and `\textrm{}` in MathJax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no real difference between these two in MathJax.  They are both implemented through the same internal function.